# -WhatIf output doesn't match actual result

Tags: powershell

Can anyone tell me why the output from using the `-WhatIf` switch on the following command doesn't match up with the real world result from running the command without the switch?

```
Dir | % {$index = 1} {
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName "s03e$($index.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0"))$($_.Name.Substring(9))" -WhatIf;
    $index++
}
```

> What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\PlexLibrary\Dragon Ball\Dragonball Z\Season 3 - Copy\DBZ - 075 - Password is Porunga.mkv Destination: D:\PlexLibrary\Dragon Ball\Dragonball Z\Season 3 - Copy\s03e01 - Password is Porunga.mkv".

According to the WhatIf output, my file should be renamed from

> DBZ - 075 - Password is Porunga

to

> s03e01 - Password is Porunga

But if I run the command the actual output is

> s03e100rd is Porunga